# Messenger Webhook subscription for other pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I have a problem with Facebook webhooks. The page/feed webhook works fine (triggers without any problems) for any page that authenticates with my app.

But the problem is that messenger webhook works only for pages that are managed by the owner of the app, pages from other users don't work, even in development mode, when these people are added as Developers/Testers. I'm trying to create an integration for an external ticket system that will support adding messenger messages as chats/tickers on the inside. As I said before everything works fine for feed and also for messenger but only if integrated page is managed by app owner.

Is there a possibility to overcome this at all? Or is it done like this by design and won't work this way ever?

I can't seem to find anything about this, so I decided to write here, maybe someone will know something.

Comment: What part specifically doesn't work? Getting the necessary token, subscribing to a page for updates, ...?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that were permissions missing - for "outside" usage except `manage_pages,publish_pages` you also have to add `read_page_mailboxes,pages_messaging,pages_messaging_phone_number` permissions and everything stars working if it is configured properly.

Comment: Can you detail out how you subscribed other pages outside of your own ownership to your app's webhooks? I can't find it for the life of me. Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Someone owning/managing this page needs to login through your application and you need to use his app-specific token to manage webhooks.
Although I believe that these permissions are now blocked for new users logging in. My app works fine for already registered users, but fails to register new ones since Facebook policy changed recently.